# .ajax() call always execute .fail() even after success in server side code (Web-api)

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, .post, ajax-request

I have an ajax call to a web-api page (**/api/attendances**). 
Its inserting a record , and return OK() as a result.

***Issue:*** insert is done correctly ,and OK will be returned, but instead of .done()/success() function, it calls .Fail()/error() .

> I tried it in two ways ($.ajax() and $.Post()), both of them ends up
>   with same result

**1)**

```
  $.post("/api/attendances", { gid: button.attr("data-gid") })
          .done(function () {
               alert("success...");
              })
          .fail(function () {
              alert("Something failed...");
              });
```

ServerSide Code:

**2)**

```
 public class AttendancesController : ApiController
  {

    //.........other initialize , ... codes in controller

   [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Attend(AttendDto dto)
    {
        //.....check for duplicate , ...

        var attendanceModel = new Attendance
        {
            AttendeeId = userId,
            gId = dto.gId
        };
        _context.Attendances.Add(attendanceModel);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

**3)**
     Defining DTO

```
  public class AttendDto
    {
        public int  gId { get; set; }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like an exception is occuring in the controller. Add .fail(funtion(error){ console.log(error);} to the Ajax funtion and display the messege.

Comment: @MarcusH thanks , it seems to be call back again , after running the first time, the error is "too much recursion" in console .

Answer (score 0):

I think its throwing an error on the SaveChanges method. You can verify by commenting the Save call and then check if the api goes to the fail function.

Comment: Thanks , I checked it. it saved correctly and goes to the right place